# Setting mouseover with jquery using variable paramaters

Tags: jquery, mouseover

```
$("#temp").mouseover(bubble(i,i));
```

bubble is function name and i is from a for loop

not sure why this isnt working, any ideas?
it just breaks the entire script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually calling the function bubble instead of passing the handler name.
Try this.

```
$("#temp").mouseover(
      (function(ip){
         return function(){
                 bubble(ip,ip);
               }; 
           })(i)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will work or not, but it's worth a try

```
$("#temp").mouseover(function() {
  bubble(i,i);
});
```

If not, you can test the mouseover in your control with this

```
$("#temp").mouseover(function() {
  alert('Mouse is over');
});
```

Then you replace the alert code with the code from the function bubble, if it doesn't work either, maybe there are some errors in your bubble function.

Hope this helps